# Style both parent and child element in css

Tags: css

I have the following structure...

```
<a href="#" class="brand-logo">
    <img src="../static/images/logo_wpc-sm.png" alt="WPC Logo" class="wpc-logo"/>
</a>
```

And I have the following css code...

```
.brand-logo {
    height: 100%;
}
 .wpc-logo {
    height: 100%;
}
```

My question: It is a way I can style both in one css code?

Comment: Like this? `.brand-logo, .wpc-logo {
    height: 100%;
}`

Comment: @LGSon post your answer so I can upvote.

Comment: Another duplicate: [combined multiple classes into one css rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215636/combined-multiple-classes-into-one-css-rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want separate class names with the same styles, use a comma `,` between CSS selectors.

```
.brand-logo,
.wpc-logo {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Or you can create a common class to apply to both elements.

```
.common {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="brand-logo common">
    <img src="../static/images/logo_wpc-sm.png" alt="WPC Logo" class="wpc-logo common"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this, using comma separation, or, in your case, the attribute selector

```css
.brand-logo, .wpc-logo {
    color: red;
}

[class$='-logo2'] {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="brand-logo">
  Red
    <span class="wpc-logo">Logo</span>
</a>

<hr>

<a href="#" class="brand-logo2">
  Blue
    <span class="wpc-logo2">Logo</span>
</a>
```